# Java EE - Return 415 status

Tags: java, api, jersey, postman

I'm creating an WEB Api with Java and Jersey and now i get 415 status code on a POST request to my API.

The request made by Postman with the Header Content-type application/json

These images show my request

[image]

[image]

And that is my code.

```
package api;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import DAO.TransactionDAO;
import DAO.UsersDAO;
import Entity.Transaction;
import Entity.Users;

@Path("/users")
public class UsersController {

    private UsersDAO dao;
    private static final String CHARSET = ";charset=UTF-8";
    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
    this.dao = new UsersDAO();
}

@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int insert(Users user){              
try{
        return this.dao.add(user);      
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.toString();
        return 0;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct. I would try to rebuild and redeploy.

Comment: You may also try to add `Accept: text/plain`.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin I'll try rebuild and tell for you the result.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin welll.. I'm tryied add `Accept: text/plain` and got the same error. 
Rebuild doesn't work too.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin I found the error. My model didn't have an empty constructor. I just create it and work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. My model didn't have an empty constructor. I just create it and work.